# Implementar método __toString()

Tags: php, symfony-2

Eu tenho um folder Previta e quando eu meto o caminho do previta.new da-me erro.

> A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type "RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina" passed to the choice field. To read a custom getter instead, set the option "property" to the desired property path.

Alguém sabe o que eu tenho de fazer?

A minha entity Maquina é:

```
<?php

namespace RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use RoqSys\Control\ControlBundle\Entity\Posto as Posto;

/**
* Maquina
*
* 
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\MaquinaRepository")
* 
*/
class Maquina 
{
    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", nullable=true, name="ciclo")
     */
    private $ciclo=0;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true, name="ultima")
     */
    private $ultima;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ControlBundle\Entity\Posto", inversedBy="maquina")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="posto_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
     */
    private $posto;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Avaria", mappedBy="maquina")
     */
    private $avaria;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Intervencao", mappedBy="maquina")
     */
    private $intervencao;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Prevista", mappedBy="maquina")
     */
    private $prevista;

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Maquina
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set ciclo
     *
     * @param integer $ciclo
     * @return Maquina
     */
    public function setCiclo($ciclo)
    {
        $this->ciclo = $ciclo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ciclo
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCiclo()
    {
        return $this->ciclo;
    }

    /**
     * Set ultima
     *
     * @param \DateTime $ultima
     * @return Maquina
     */
    public function setUltima($ultima)
    {
        $this->ultima = $ultima;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ultima
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUltima()
    {
        return $this->ultima;
    }

    /**
     * Set posto
     *
     * @param Posto $posto
     * @return Maquina
     */
    public function setPosto($posto)
    {
        $this->posto = $posto;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get posto
     *
     * @return Posto
     */
    public function getPosto()
    {
        return $this->posto;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->getId();
    }
}
```

E a maquina.new

```
{% block content -%}
    <h1>Nova Máquina</h1>
    <br>
    <ul class="record_actions">
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('manutencao_maquina') }}">
                Voltar para a lista
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Número</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Endereço</th>
                <th>Estação</th>
                <th>Protocolo</th>
                <th>Ativo</th>
                <th>Ler</th>
                <th>Opções</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for posto in postos %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{ path('gestao_posto_show', { 'id': posto.id }) }}" >{{ posto.id }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ posto.numero }}</td>
                    <td>{{ posto.descricao }}</td>
                    <td>{{ posto.endereco }}</td>
                    <td>{{ posto.estacao }}</td>
                    <td>{{ posto.protocolo }}</td>
                    <td>{{ posto.ativo }}</td>
                    <td>{{ posto.ler }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ path('manutencao_maquina_create', { 'id': posto.id }) }}">Converter</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock%}
```

Prevista.php

```
<?php

namespace RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina as Maquina;

/**
 * Prevista
 *
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\PrevistaRepository")
 */
class Prevista {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true, name="contagem")
     */
    private $contagem;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true, name="duracao")
     */
    private $duracao;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, name="titulo")
     */
    private $titulo;

    /**
     * @var string 
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, name="ficha")
     */
    private $ficha;

    /**
     * @var string 
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, name="descricao")
     */
    private $descricao;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true, name="ultima")
     */
    private $ultima;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina", inversedBy="prevista")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="maquina_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $maquina;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set contagem
     *
     * @param integer $contagem
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setContagem($contagem) {
        $this->contagem = $contagem;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contagem
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getContagem() {
        return $this->contagem;
    }

    /**
     * Set duracao
     *
     * @param integer $duracao
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setDuracao($duracao) {
        $this->duracao = $duracao;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get duracao
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDuracao() {
        return $this->duracao;
    }

    /**
     * Set titulo
     *
     * @param string $titulo
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setTitulo($titulo) {
        $this->titulo = $titulo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titulo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitulo() {
        return $this->titulo;
    }

    /**
     * Set ficha
     *
     * @param string $ficha
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setFicha($ficha) {
        $this->ficha = $ficha;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ficha
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFicha() {
        return $this->ficha;
    }

    /**
     * Set descricao
     *
     * @param string $descricao
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setDescricao($descricao) {
        $this->descricao = $descricao;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descricao
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescricao() {
        return $this->descricao;
    }

    /**
     * Set ultima
     *
     * @param \DateTime $ultima
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setUltima($ultima) {
        $this->ultima = $ultima;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ultima
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUltima() {
        return $this->ultima;
    }

    /**
     * Set maquina
     *
     * @param Maquina $maquina
     * @return Maquina
     */
    public function setMaquina($maquina) {
        $this->maquina = $maquina;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get maquina
     *
     * @return \Maquina
     */
    public function getMaquina() {
        return $this->maquina;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando selecionar uma entidade do tipo `Maquina` mas a aplicação não sabe qual atributo exibir. Você precisa definir no form type qual atributo exibir ou implementar o método `__toString` na entidade `Maquina`.

Se você preferir alterar o form type, coloque algo assim:

```
$builder
    ->add('maquina', null, [
        'property' => 'id' // ou qualquer outra propriedade que você queira
    ])
```

Se você preferir implementar o `__toString`:

```
class Maquina
{
    /* propriedades, getters e setters */

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->getId(); // deve-se retornar uma string
    }
}
```

Comment: eu meti isto na classe class Maquina
{
    /* propriedades, getters e setters */

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getId();
    }
} e pareceu-me agora este erro. Catchable Fatal Error: Method RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina::__toString() must return a string value in /var/www/roqsys/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ObjectChoiceList.php line 254

Comment: O Symfony espera uma string no retorno desse método. Use `(string)$this->getId()` ou `strval($this->getId())`. Editei minha resposta.

Comment: erro An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/roqsys/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/IdentityTranslator.php line 65") in "/var/www/roqsys/vendor/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/Braincrafted/Bundle/BootstrapBundle/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap.html.twig"

Comment: O atributo que você está querendo retornar é um array ou uma coleção de entidades? Você precisa retornar algo que identifique aquela entidade.

Comment: veja a minha resposta foi o que fiz mas dá-me erro. An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/roqsys/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/IdentityTranslator.php line 65") in "/var/www/roqsys/vendor/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/Braincrafted/Bundle/BootstrapBundle/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap.html.twig".

Comment: Pelo que eu notei na mensagem de erro, você conseguiu arrumar o erro da pergunta mas está dando problema de tradução em alguma parte da sua view. O Symfony está tentando traduzir uma string mas está recebndo um array no lugar.

Comment: mas isso será a onde? no Controlador?

Comment: Você está usando o método `trans` nos templates ou `trans()` no PHP? Provavelmente é em algum desses que está acusando o erro.

Comment: nem um nem outro

Comment: como eu defino isto: To read a custom getter instead, set the option "property" to the desired property path.

Comment: É o primeiro exemplo que coloquei na resposta. Para "traduzir" uma model para um formulário (e vice-versa) você usa form types. Coloque a linha acima no form type do posto.

Comment: Rodrigo Rigotti eu ainda não conseguir resolver o problema An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/roqsys/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/IdentityTranslator.php line 65") in "/var/www/roqsys/vendor/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/Braincrafted/Bundle/BootstrapBundle/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap.html.twig". Será que você me consegue ajudar?

Comment: Você não quer compartilhar seu código, e assim dá pra analisá-lo mais a fundo?

Comment: que código é que compartilhar, o código está em cima, na tag.

Comment: O problema é que o erro que você citou é bem genérico e pode se originar de vários jeitos. Pelo que parece, acredito que seja algum formulário que você esteja tentando renderizar e um dos componentes dele está configurado de maneira errada. Mas como eu disse, é uma das possibilidades de originar esse erro.

Comment: mas eu não estou conseguindo resolver o problema.

Comment: Se o problema da pergunta foi resolvido (isso é, se a mensagem de erro que originou a pergunta não aparece mais), valide a resposta e crie outra pergunta com ênfase nesse erro que estamos discutindo. Com certeza haverá mais gente tentando ajudar com esse problema.